# Past Participle with sehen

Tags: past-participle

How do I use the past participle in the following sentence:

> It was interesting to see it performed as a play.

Should I put the participle before the *sehen*?

> Es war sehr interessant, es wie ein Schauspiel aufgeführt zu sehen.

Comment: Es war interessant, es als Schauspiel aufgeführt zu sehen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Und das ist auch schon die Antwort.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz [+1] Aber, wäre es nicht konstruktiver das als Antwort zu posten? (Frage nur…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Carsten Schultz commented:

> Es war interessant, es als Schauspiel aufgeführt zu sehen

(In this case it also could be:

> Es war interessant, es als Schauspiel aufgeführt gesehen zu bekommen )

Comment: The second variant doesn't make sense. To cover the figurative meaning of *see*, it should be "... aufgeführt zu bekommen", or to preserve the English ambiguity you could use"... aufgeführt zu sehen zu bekommen".